# Got a java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have added two `LinearLayouts` and on those layouts, I add dynamically `Checkboxes`. The final purpose is to store data in a database.

I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.freedomkitchen.sonali.freedomkitchen/com.freedomkitchen.sonali.freedomkitchenAndroidApp.AddRecipes}:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Can you help me to find the problem, please? Thanks.

This is my code:

```
public class AddRecipes extends AppCompatActivity {
    static int a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0;
    static int id=0;
    public int x;
    int idvalueVeg;
    int idvalueFruits;
    int idvalueGrains;
    int idvalueDairy;
    int idvalueSeaFood;
    int end_of_sup_ing;
    int sup_ing_id;
    ArrayList<String> Main_Ingredients;
    ArrayList<String> Supporting_Ingredients;
    LinearLayout ll;
    LinearLayout ll2;
    Spinner FoodCatValue;
    public String MealSelected;
    EditText RecipeNameValue;
    public   Spinner sItems;


    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;


    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;


    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private View mContentView;
    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {

            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };
    private View mControlsView;
    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed display of UI elements
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
    private boolean mVisible;
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addrecipes);

         ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chk_layout);
        ll2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chk_layout2);
        FoodCatValue = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerFoodCat);



        Resources res = getResources();
        String[] Appetizers  = res.getStringArray(R.array.Appetizer_Meals);
        String[] Main_Course  = res.getStringArray(R.array.Main_Course_Meals);
        String[] Desserts  = res.getStringArray(R.array.Desserts_Meals);

        ArrayList<String> AppetizerList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(Appetizers));
        ArrayList<String> Main_CourseList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(Main_Course));
        ArrayList<String> DessertList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(Desserts));

        if(FoodCatValue.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Appetizers")){
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, AppetizerList);

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMealCat);
            sItems.setAdapter(adapter);
            getMealSelectedVal();
        }

        else if(FoodCatValue.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Main Course"))

            {
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Main_CourseList);

                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMealCat);
                sItems.setAdapter(adapter);
                getMealSelectedVal();

            }
        else if(FoodCatValue.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Dessert")){

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, DessertList);

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMealCat);
            sItems.setAdapter(adapter);
            getMealSelectedVal();

        }


                RecipeNameValue =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.RecipeName);

                DB_Access mydb=new DB_Access(this);
                ArrayList<String> Vegetables=mydb.getIngredients(1);
                ArrayList<String> Fruits=mydb.getIngredients(2);
                ArrayList<String> Dairy=mydb.getIngredients(3);
                ArrayList<String> Grains=mydb.getIngredients(4);
                ArrayList<String> Seafood=mydb.getIngredients(5);
                ArrayList<String> Sup_Ing=mydb.getSupportingIngredients();
                final TextView VegTv = new TextView(this);
                VegTv.setText("Vegetables");
                ll.addView(VegTv);
                for (x=0;x<Vegetables.size(); x++,id++) {
                    final CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
                    checkbox.setId(id);
                    String Item = Vegetables.get(x);
                    checkbox.setText(Item);
                    ll.addView(checkbox);
                    idvalueVeg=id;
                }
                TextView FruitsTv = new TextView(this);
                FruitsTv.setText("Fruits");
                ll.addView(FruitsTv);



                for (x=0;x<Fruits.size(); x++,id++) {
                    CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
                    checkbox.setId(id);
                    String Item = Fruits.get(x);
                    checkbox.setText(Item);
                    ll.addView(checkbox);
                    idvalueFruits=id;

                }
                TextView GrainsTv = new TextView(this);
                GrainsTv.setText("Grains");
                ll.addView(GrainsTv);

                for (x=0;x<Grains.size(); x++,id++) {
                    CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
                    checkbox.setId(id);
                    String Item = Grains.get(x);
                    checkbox.setText(Item);
                    ll.addView(checkbox);
                    idvalueGrains=id;


                }
                TextView DairyTv = new TextView(this);
                DairyTv.setText("Dairy");
                ll.addView(DairyTv);

                for(x=0;x<Dairy.size(); x++,id++) {
                    CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
                    checkbox.setId(id);
                    String Item = Dairy.get(x);
                    checkbox.setText(Item);
                    ll.addView(checkbox);
                    idvalueDairy=id;

                }
                TextView SeafoodTv = new TextView(this);
                SeafoodTv.setText("Seafood");
                ll.addView(DairyTv);
                for(x=0;x<Seafood.size(); x++,id++) {
                    CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
                    checkbox.setId(id);
                    String Item = Seafood.get(x);
                    checkbox.setText(Item);
                    ll2.addView(checkbox);
                    idvalueSeaFood=id;

                }
             TextView supIng = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sup_ingTextView);
                DairyTv.setText("Supporting Ingredients");
                 ll.addView(supIng);
                sup_ing_id = idvalueSeaFood;

                for(x=0;x<Sup_Ing.size(); x++,id++) {
                    CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
                    checkbox.setId(id);
                    String Item = Sup_Ing.get(x);
                    checkbox.setText(Item);
                    ll.addView(checkbox);
                    end_of_sup_ing=id;
                }

            }

    public void getMealSelectedVal(){
        MealSelected= sItems.getSelectedItem().toString();

    }

    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }


    private void hide() {
        // Hide UI first
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;

        // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        // Show the system bar
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        mVisible = true;

        // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }


    public void btnAddRecipes(View v){
        GetInfo();

        DB_Access mydb=new DB_Access(this);
        EditText ins =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.RecipeTextArea);

        mydb.adduserRecipes(FoodCatValue.getSelectedItem().toString(),MealSelected,RecipeNameValue.getText().toString(), Main_Ingredients,Supporting_Ingredients,ins.getText().toString());


    }
    public void GetInfo(){
        Main_Ingredients=new ArrayList<String>(200);
        Supporting_Ingredients=new ArrayList<String>(200);
        for(x=0;x<id;x++){
            CheckBox cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(x);
            if(cb.isChecked()){
                   {
                       String item=cb.getText().toString();
                       Main_Ingredients.add(item);


                }

            }


        }
        //disp main ing
        for(int i=0;i<Main_Ingredients.size();i++){

            Log.i("Main_Ing:",Main_Ingredients.get(i));
        }


        for(x=sup_ing_id;x<=end_of_sup_ing;x++){
            CheckBox cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(x);
            if(cb.isChecked()){
                {
                    String item=cb.getText().toString();
                    Supporting_Ingredients.add(item);


                }

            }

        }
        for(int i=0;i<Supporting_Ingredients.size();i++){

            Log.i("Sup_Ing:",Supporting_Ingredients.get(i));
        }

    }
 }
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cdd2ea"
    android:id="@+id/RL"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonAddRecipes">



    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/l_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Add a New Recipe"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Food Category :"
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="47dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="244dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerFoodCat"
            android:entries="@array/Food_Cat"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Meal Category :"
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="47dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="244dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerMealCat"

            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Recipe Name :"
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="47dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="271dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/RecipeName"
            android:hint="Enter Recipe Name"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Main Ingredients:"
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_marginStart="47dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/chk_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/sup_ingTextView"
            android:layout_marginStart="47dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/chk_layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="303dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Instructions :"
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/RecipeTextArea"
            android:editable="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:minLines="6"
            android:maxLines="6"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:hint="Enter Recipe Instructions here."
            android:background="#fafafa"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:padding="24dp"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Recipe"
    android:id="@+id/buttonAddRecipes"
    android:capitalize="words"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:background="#4052b5"
    android:textColor="#fefefe"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_select_dialog_padding_start_material"
    android:onClick="btnAddRecipes"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception is fired then you try to add some view twice to layout.

You copypasted your code and didn't change it here

```
TextView SeafoodTv = new TextView(this);
SeafoodTv.setText("Seafood");
ll.addView(DairyTv);
```

I beleive it should be

```
TextView SeafoodTv = new TextView(this);
SeafoodTv.setText("Seafood");
ll.addView(SeafoodTv);
```

To avoid such mistakes it's better to put static views in xml layout.

Comment: Still the problem exists.

Comment: @SonaliSeth You can find exact line number what caused exception in it's stacktrace outlput in logcat. I think you have some more similar typos